# Knockout+DataTables Filtering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have table with data, want to be able filter rows in it, data is coming from service and binded via knockout:

```
<table class="table bordered hovered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: usersList">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: UserName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

function getUsers() {
    $.getJSON('/api/aspnetusers', null, function (users) {
        ViewModel.usersList.pushAll(users);
    });
}

getUsers();

$(function () {
    $('.table').DataTable();
});
```

After entering something into filter input i always get:

```
 No data available in table
```

Comment: Seems like "users" does not have the data you expect. I would use Chrome's dev tools and "console.debug(users);" or "debugger;" row before "ViewModel.usersList.pushAll(users)" to find out what's received from server.
Also, if you are windows user, should try Fiddler from Telerik (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff HTTP requests/responses

Comment: i have users, i see them all, but when i try filter them, binding brokes

Comment: Please provide code of filtering  also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a timing issue, try waiting until the data is loaded before initializing DataTables:

```
$.getJSON('/api/aspnetusers', null, function (users) {
   ViewModel.usersList.pushAll(users);
}).done(function(){ $('.table').DataTable(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it... I have made a jsfiddle showing this:

To get this to work I had to add two callback methods to the original knockout foreach binding definition. I am currently trying to get these events into the newest version of knockout. I needed to add a beforeRenderAll and afterRenderAll callback to destroy the datatable and reinitialize the datatable after the knockouts foreach binding adds the html. This works like a charm The JSFiddle showing this has a fully editable jquery datatable bound to the ViewModel through knockout.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DataTablesForEach = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        key = "DataTablesForEach_Initialized";

        var newValue = function () {
            return {
                data: value.data || value,
                beforeRenderAll: function(el, index, data){
                    if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {                                   
                        $(element).closest('table').DataTable().destroy();
                    }
                },
                afterRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {
                    $(element).closest('table').DataTable(value.options);
                }

            };
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

        //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there is currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
        if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (value.data || value.length)) {
            ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
        }

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
```

};

[jsfiddle with bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/wv3rjygy/)

[jsfiddle with jqueryUI](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/z8us2aej/)